# Salvar informações da aplicação ao sair (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

estou fazendo um formulário pelo tkinter e queria saber como eu posso salvar as informações dele caso o usuário feche a aplicação pelo X vermelho da pagina, para que depois quando ele entrar de novo não precisar repetir tudo ele já escreveu. Porem queria que ele só salvasse caso ele feche.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter 



class jogo:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.Formulario()
        
        
    def Formulario (self):
        self.formulario = ttk.Frame(root)
        self.formulario.pack()
        v= tkinter.IntVar()
        ttk.Checkbutton(self.formulario
                        ,text = "check1"
                        ,variable = v
                        ).pack()

        lbl_entry = ttk.Label(self.formulario, text = "nome:")
        lbl_entry.pack()
        entry = ttk.Entry(self.formulario)
        entry.pack()
        lbl_entry2 = ttk.Label(self.formulario, text = "cidade:")
        lbl_entry2.pack()
        entry2 = ttk.Entry(self.formulario)
        entry2.pack()
        
        bt= ttk.Button(self.formulario,text = "savar", command = lambda : self.Save(entry.get(),entry2.get()))
        bt.pack()
        
    def Save(self,a,b):
        print(a)
        print(b)
        
        
        
root = tkinter.Tk()
jogo(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar um Protocolo no seu root pra detectar o fechamento do usuário. Fiz umas alterações e algumas anotações para você entender melhor

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter


class jogo:
def __init__(self,root):
    self.Formulario()

# Função que é chamada no botão salvar e quando clica no X do programa
def SalvarInformacoes(self, finalizarPrograma = True):
    # Cria um arquivo
    with open("testeFile.txt", 'w') as f:
        # Escreve as informações que foram preenchidas no front, pode ser trocado por um banco de dados
        f.write(self.Nome.get() + '\n')
        f.write(self.Cidade.get() + '\n')
    if (finalizarPrograma):
        root.destroy()

def CarregarInformacoes(self):
    try:
        # Função que é chamda quando termina de desenhar o formulário, inserindo a informação que está preenchida no arquivo
        with open("testeFile.txt", 'r') as f:
            nome = f.readline().replace("\n", "")
            cidade = f.readline().replace("\n", "")
            self.Nome.insert(0, nome)
            self.Cidade.insert(0, cidade)
        #caso o arquivo não exista vai cair no exception e simplesmente n vai carregar nada
    except Exception:
        pass

def Formulario (self):
    # Protocolo que detecta o click no X do Frame
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.SalvarInformacoes)
    self.formulario = ttk.Frame(root)
    self.formulario.pack()
    v= tkinter.IntVar()
    ttk.Checkbutton(self.formulario
                    ,text = "check1"
                    ,variable = v
                    ).pack()

    lbl_entry = ttk.Label(self.formulario, text = "nome:")
    lbl_entry.pack()
    self.Nome = ttk.Entry(self.formulario)
    self.Nome.pack()
    lbl_entry2 = ttk.Label(self.formulario, text = "cidade:")
    lbl_entry2.pack()
    self.Cidade = ttk.Entry(self.formulario)
    self.Cidade.pack()
    
    bt= ttk.Button(self.formulario,text = "salvar", command = lambda : self.SalvarInformacoes(finalizarPrograma = False))
    bt.pack()
    self.CarregarInformacoes()
    
root = tkinter.Tk()
jogo(root)
root.mainloop()
```